# How to avoid bootstrap modal disappearance when auto postback in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Am using vb.net in my asp.net project also bootstrap 4. I have two dropdown list inside a modal, when the user select an item from the first dropdown list, the second list will be sorted.

The problem is, when the user select from the first list the page will **postback** which casing the modal to disappear. I tried to use `<asp:UpdatePanel></asp:UpdatePanel>` tag, but it didn't work.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions! Here's my code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AddNew" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add New</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row pb-3">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" class="browser-default custom-select form-control-sm" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" class="browser-default custom-select form-control-sm" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-sm">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="User Name..."></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListGroup" class="browser-default custom-select form-control-sm" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" runat="server" Text="Add" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do here. A post back will blow out a jQuery.UI dialog, a ajaxtoolkit popup, and of course a bootstrap dialog.

This means and suggests that while you can pop a dialog and let a user choose or click on something? That action can be though as ALSO the means to close that dialog if the user choice is to cause a post-back (saves you having to write code to close the dialog!!!).

If you need something like a cascade combo box?

Then I would NOT use a popup, but simply use a update panel, and display the several objects.

If you really want the cascade combo box or whatever in the popup? Then you have to use JavaScript and ajax calls to the web page - no post backs allowed. You CAN do this, but it quite a bit of extra work. So, I would suggest that you avoid the popup for such kinds of work, since you not only lose the GREAT nice easy to use button code stubs and code behind (the reason why asp.net and web forms are oh so easy to use!!!).

So, you have to get say a little bit creative. You can put all the options say inside of a "div" section, and hide or show that section with code behind.

And then show/hide the area on the form with say this:

```
myDiv.Style("Display") = "normal"
```

So hide/show a area on the form. Thus in that panel, we can have two combo boxes (choose state/province and then cascade to the city choice). When the user selects a city, (and auto postback) then we shove that selecting into the text box, and hide the div. All works with just a few lines of code, and no jQuery or bootstrap dialogs.

So the general rule?

Pop a dialog - user can enter data, check box a few things, enter comments and then they hit ok button or whatever. But that button will do a post-back and will close the dialog. So that is the design pattern.

If you break from above? Then you can build dialog forms, but you have to wire up any actions of that dialog as ajax calls. A post back causes the WHOLE browser page to travel up to server. Code behind runs, changes anything on that page and then the whole page travels back down to client and THEN is re-displayed. I should ALSO add that the web server page is now gone, does NOT exist server side and all variables in code etc. are also gone.

The code behind NEVER interacts with the user. it ONLY interacts with the web page in that round trip and ONLY during the short time that the page is up on the server, and code behind runs. So a post back will blow out any JavaScript running on that page, since the whole page travels up to server, code behind runs, and WHOLE page THEN travels back down to client, the browser loads the page AND THEN STARTS RUNNING the JavaScript. Since a post back sends the page to the server and THEN will send the WHOLE page back, then you can't have a post-back run and keep your JavaScript popus etc. running, and worse the browser re-loads the whole page, and the JavaScript code STARTS over running again!!!

So if you really want to do this? Then you have to make ajax calls.

So the rule and design pattern? A post-back is to close the dialog and you only can have or allow one post-back as the "final" action of that dialog. Break this rule, and you then having to hand code up a LOT of JavaScript and ajax calls.

So the answer is you can't do a post back. You can do this with jQuery.ui dialogs and insert a iframe into the dialog. So you put the asp.net web page and buttons inside of a iframe - but then again, that popup in MOST cases will want to interact with the current page and a iframe does not let you do this for all practical use cases anyway.

I have thus found by changing my design patterns and assumptions, then you simply have to cook up slightly different approaches to your UI designs, and thus once done, then you can do this.

So, for example, you might pop one list to select from, and then when the user selects a value (post back) you then say perhaps popup another list for the user to select. So you can pop a list for display, and the user selection of course can be a post-back (and often it will be). Then code behind can trigger another dialog and you get that input.

Comment: Thank You! I really thought this cannot happened in different way. But you really give me another perspective